# No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock (*) failed

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, apache2.4, apache-modules

I have such virtual host settings

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

phpinfo() shows that my site has a version of php 5.6. All right!

Now I am trying to restrict the rights with Mod_Ruid2. I added the following to my virtual host

```
RDocumentChRoot /var /www/html
<Directory "/www/html/">
        Require all granted
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin0 admin0
</Directory>
```

after trying to get to the site I see an error in the logs

```
[Sun Oct 13 16:09:02.492117 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 13571] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock (*) failed
[Sun Oct 13 16:09:02.492194 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 13571] [client 192.168.0.110:47622] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

I've just faced the same issue while trying to run apache(2.4) + php(7.2) over CentOS 8.

```
[Thu Jan 09 06:59:10.420499 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 121:tid 139846433412864] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Thu Jan 09 06:59:10.420535 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 121:tid 139846433412864] [client 127.0.0.1:55580] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

To solve this, I had to launch a service called "php-fpm" (sudo systemctl enable --now php-fpm), that led me to another error:

```
[09-Jan-2020 07:07:09] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/www.sock': No such file or directory (2)
[09-Jan-2020 07:07:09] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

That was caused by the folder /run/php-fpm not existing.

```
mkdir -p /run/php-fpm/
```

After that, just launched again php-fpm, this time without errors and apache+php worked like a charm.

Note that there is a small difference between your error and mine, the paths are a bit different. Instead of "/run/php-fpm/" you should create "/var/run/php/".

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue, in my case I could fix it by restarting PHP fpm service, by running code:

> `sudo service phpx.x-fpm restart`

OS: centos
Webserver: nginx

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue on `CentOS 8` and `Apache 2.4.37` and after many hour research in internet , i can't found any solution for unix domain proxy.

i don't know this is a bug or bad document?

**for resolve this problem** only you must be replace `proxy:unix:/YOUR_PATH` with `proxy:unix://YOUR_PATH`.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:unix:///var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

*notice : `...|fcgi://localhost/` must be exists.*

**after your change this setting the new problem appears :**

`File not found.`

this error is good because we were able connected to `php-fpm` from `apache`.

i think this problem is bug. please see this link.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55322

**for resolve this problem** you must be implement this structure :

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
  #your configs ....
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/php-fpm.d/example.com.conf

```
[example.com]
;your configs...

chroot = /
access.log = /var/www/$pool/logs/phpfpm-access-$pool.log
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/www/$pool/public_html

;your configs...
```

Comment: Addind a "/" make the next path section disappear for me : attempt to connect to Unix domain socket run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed to attempt >> connect to Unix domain socket /php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed. 

The correct path is /run... you had /var before, adding a / remove it, that why your path become the correct one. You patched a first mistake if I understand the situation.

Answer (score 1):

To run php scripts under php5.4-fpm, You must install php5.4-fpm .

On Ubuntu 22.04 its posible with:

```
sudo apt install php5.6 php5.6-fpm -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same issue, I commented this part of code in my drupal.con (could be another one for you)

```
#<FilesMatch \.php$>
#    SetHandler proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost/
#</FilesMatch>
```

And the website just show up. Apparently I did not need it on this serveur (redhat 7), but I needed it in my CentOS for the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Please note I had this come up today and I found the solution on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/897691/php-fpm-error-503-attempt-to-connect-to-unix-domain-socket-failed). pfrenssen's answer specifically. Note the field name tripped me up for an hour as `listen.group` and `group` both exist. I then needed to comment a line `listen.acl_users` out which was uncommented by default. It important to note that the `www-data` user I am using is the user I have predefined (non-default) apache user. I believe this to be the underlying cause. Below is my one liner to change these values. Use `cp /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default` first to help test as sed modifies the file in place.

```sh
sed -i  -e 's/user = apache/user = www-data/g' \
        -e 's/group = apache/group = www-data/g' \
        -e 's/;listen.owner = nobody/listen.owner = www-data/g' \
        -e 's/;listen.group = nobody/listen.group = www-data/g' \
        -e 's/;listen.mode = 0660/listen.mode = 0660/g' \
        -e 's/listen.acl_users = apache,nginx/;listen.acl_users = apache,nginx/g' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```